# Concatenate URL text from UITextField to global variable NSURL

Tags: swift, ios8, nsurl

I have a variable httpUrl in my rootViewController that all the other ViewControllers inherit from.

```
var httpUrl = NSURL(string: "http://")
```

In another ViewController I have an UITextField @IBAction that I want the user's input and then add it to the var httpUrl.

```
@IBAction func urlTextField(sender: AnyObject) {

    //NSURL(string: self.urlTextField.text)

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate URLs or how to pass them between view controllers?

Comment: Updated question.  Yes, I am asking how to concatenate URL's.  Taking the users input via UITextField and concatenate to the var httpUrl.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is probably to create a string of the desired format and then turn it into an URL, since there isn't really a way to concatenate two URLs.

```
let urlString = "http://\(urlTextField.text)"
let combinedUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The error is .text isn't available for the TextField.  I tried IBAction sender by AnyObject or no arguments to no avail.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error? Is it a compile or run time error?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out.  I needed to create a Singleton in my base.swift for the other view Controllers to inherit from.  Thank you for your help!